# Await Async Event Invocation in Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: c#, events, async-await, blazor-webassembly

I have some code in Blazor WASM that looks like this:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public interface ICommandProcessor
{
    Task<bool> Process(ICommand cmd);
}

public class CustomerService
{
    public ICommandProcessor Processor { get; }

    public CustomerService(ICommandProcessor processor)
    {
        Processor = processor;
    }
    
    public async Task<bool> ProcessCommand(ICommand cmd)
    {
        var res = await Processor.Process(cmd);
        if (res && CustomerChanged is not null)
        {
            //make sure all subscribers have processed before returning
            await CustomerChanged.Invoke(cmd.Customer);
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    public event Func<Customer,Task> CustomerChanged;
}
```

My desired result is to have all the subscribers to CustomerChanged entirely executed prior to the ProcessCommand method returning a bool.  The subscribers to CustomerChanged have async code in them.  I have verified through logging that this works as expected. I have also verified that if I do not await that the CustomerChanged.Invoke method that the ProcessCommand method will return prior to at least some of the subscribers entirely executing

Now I had read on StackOverflow that one shouldn't await an async event w/o special considerations; however, my example works. Is this a valid pattern in Blazor WASM or is my code just working coincidentally?  If not, how do I achieve my desired goal.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I had read on StackOverflow that one shouldn't await an async event w/o special considerations; however, my example works.

So, [here's what is happening](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/delegates#196-delegate-invocation?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). Delegates (including events) can contain multiple handlers. When a delegate is invoked it returns the *last* return value (i.e., `Task`) from the collection of handlers. So the code as currently written will start all the handlers and then (asynchronously) wait for the last one to complete.

Since your delegate type returns `Task`, the best solution IMO is the [Task-Returning Delegate Solution](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/02/async-oop-5-events.html) described on my blog. The idea is to use `Delegate.GetInvocationList` to get a list of all the handlers, invoke them all, and then use `await Task.WhenAll` to wait for them *all* to complete (instead of just the last one). Something like this:

```
if (res && CustomerChanged is not null)
{
  //make sure all subscribers have processed before returning
  var handlers = CustomerChanged
      .GetInvocationList()
      .Cast<Func<Customer, Task>>()
      .ToList();
  var tasks = handlers
      .Select(h => h(cmd.Customer))
      .ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```